# Changing a timeline tracks height in Unity to save space

Tags: unity-game-engine

The tracks in my timeline are massive. If I max out the window on my 15" macbook I can see 9 tracks in total. Is it possible to change their height somehow?

I feel like this should be possible as I've seen [screenshots](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TimelineTrackList.html) where they are a lot smaller, but nothing I do seems to work. Zooming only works on x-axis and there doesn't seem to be any scale handles at the edge of the tracks...

[image]

Comment: try using your mouse wheel?

Comment: @eddge not for changing the height. That just scrolls down the list

Answer (score 2):

Use Crtl + mousewheel to change height of track...

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem, too. Although there seems to have no direct way to change the track height, I found a way modify the preference file of Timeline editor.

Find a file located under your project's Library/Timeline folder (its name should be xxxxx.pref), open it with a text editor, change the number after trackScale to 1, and you should be fine.

[Screenshot: Timeline preference screenshot, the left one has trackScale of 1, whether the right one has trackScale of 3.79](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wsDl.png)

Comment: Thank you for this alternative method, I came to this question looking for a similar issue and learning about the pref file allowed me to address it!

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll through using mouse wheel.
Last time  I checked, the height was not changeable. You may have seen `Track Group`.
Also, a good idea is to group the tracks. To add a `Track group`, click the `Add` button and select `Track Group` from the `Add` menu. You can also Right-click an empty area of the `Track list` and select `Track Group` from the context menu.
More about this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TimelineOrganizingTrackGroups.html